# starter_fs.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --nvmain-config

Tags: gem5, nvmain

I am running gem5 patched with NVMain. But when I am going to run then getting error unrecognized element --nvmain-config. I have seen all the other article is using this argument and their program run also. I also changed script from starter_fs.py to fs.py but still no good. Please help me how i can run it.[image]

```
I have added the picture for better understanding .
usage: starter_fs.py [-h] [--dtb DTB] [--kernel KERNEL]
                     [--disk-image DISK_IMAGE] [--script SCRIPT]
                     [--cpu {hpi,atomic,minor}] [--cpu-freq CPU_FREQ]
                     [--num-cores NUM_CORES]
                     [--mem-type {NVMainMemory,HBM_1000_4H_1x128,DRAMCtrl,DDR3_2133_8x8,HBM_1000_4H_1x64,GDDR5_4000_2x32,HMC_2500_1x32,LPDDR3_1600_1x32,WideIO_200_1x128,DDR4_2400_8x8,DDR3_1600_8x8,DDR4_2400_4x16,DDR4_2400_16x4,SimpleMemory,LPDDR2_S4_1066_1x32}]
                     [--mem-channels MEM_CHANNELS] [--mem-ranks MEM_RANKS]
                     [--mem-size MEM_SIZE] [--checkpoint] [--restore RESTORE]
starter_fs.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --nvmain-config=./Configs/PCM_ISSCC_2012_4GB.config
```

Comment: I haven't used gem5 with NVMain, but you could search for a line containing "nvmain_config" within the configs folder (e.g., grep -nr "nvmain_config" configs/). If such line doesn't exist, that command does not exist, so you probably have the wrong gem5 version (this is possibly the correct one: https://github.com/cyjseagull/gem5-nvmain-hybrid-simulator , but, again, I haven't used it, so I don't know for sure).

Comment: Did you able to run gem5 via the steps provided in the article.